# Firebase-admin won't write to database, gives no errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

Firebase admin isn't writing to the database.

I am instantiating the database:

```
var db = admin.database();
```

Then setting up a reference to the table I want:

```
var systemsRef = db.ref("systems/");
```

I then have a function to check if the 'system', (an encrypted hardware id), exists.

```
function isSystemRegistered(id){
  var isTrue;
  systemsRef.once('value', function(snapshot) {
      isTrue = (snapshot.hasChild(id))? true : false;
  });
  return isTrue;
}
```

Which, as of yet returns `false`; which is `true`, because it doesn't exist yet. If the system doesn't exist, it writes the data.

```
const sysID = getSysID();
var sys.info.name = generateUniqueSystemName();

if(isSystemRegistered(sysID){
  console.log("system is already registered!");
} else {
  msystemsRef.set({
      sysID : sys.info.name
    }, function(error){
        console.log('There was an error while attempting to write to database: ' + error);
      });
  });
}
```

I've experimented, and temporarily made my prototype database fully public for a few minutes, just to be sure my `rules` weren't the issue... They weren't: still no bueno. No writes to the database... and **no errors**.

I tried a different `set`, just be sure:

```
msystemsRef.set("I'm writing data", function(error) {
  if (error) {
    alert("Data could not be saved." + error);
  } else {
    alert("Data saved successfully.");
  }
});
```

Again, I'm using an admin account, with `public` rules, so I should see a now `I'm writing data` table, just below root. Nothing...

So I switched tactics and attempted to push to the database with the canned tutorial, with my database *still* fully public:

```
systemsRef.push({sysID : sys.info.name});
```

And nothing... Want am I missing?

Comment: Did you get this resolved!? I am having the same issue...

Comment: @FamicTech No I've not solved it yet. It's still an issue - I filed a bug with Google at a conference. But we'll see -- it's difficult to rise above the noise.

Answer (score 1):

In `isSystemRegistered` you're returning the synchronized value of `isTrue` which is `undefined`.

You should return the promise of the `.once('value')` method and in the calling method attach a `then()` to check if it exists.

You can also use the `snapshot.exists()` to check on a reference for existence.

**Edit:**

Suggested edit:

```
var systemRef = admin.database('system');

function isSystemRegistered(id) {
  return systemRef.child(id).once('value')
    .then(function (snap) {
      return snap.exists();
    });
}

function writeData(aSystem) {
  var sysId = generateUniqueSystemName();
  return systemRef.child(sysId)
    .once('value')
    .then(function (snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.exists()) {
        return systemRef.child(sysId).update(aSystem);
      }

      // Here `sysId === snapshot.key`
      return systemRef.child(sysId).set(aSystem);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
       console.error(err);
    });
}
```

Running on Raspberry Pi raises some more questions.

- How does it connect to the internet?
- How fast is the connection?
- What NodeJS version do you run?
- Did this run successfully on your PC?

Comment: I'll check this out tomorrow and get back with you, thanks!

Comment: I'm going to up vote because you are correct, though, I failed to mention this issue is happening on Raspberry Pi (and only there), a fact I hadn't thoroughly verified when I asked the question originally. I'll update my question. Please refer to my comment on another answer for more detail if you like.

Comment: Which NodeJS version are you using on your raspberry?

Comment: @NonCreature0714 I'm seeing this same issue also running on a Raspberry Pi. Did you find out if that was a direct cause? if so how?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the credentials and databaseURL are correct.

```
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: databaseURL
});
```

Check if they're matching - credential from one app and databaseURL from another existing app could produce such result.

If you are not loading credential's data from file but from somewhere else, make sure it's not modified - I had an issue with newlines in private key when putting the credential's data to shell variable.

Comment: You bring up a good point, I'll double check the credentials and URL. I think they are correct, because I tested using the same credential/URL on my MacBook and LinuxVM, where it worked. But where I ran into an issue is using the same code/packages on Raspberry Pi, where it didn't work. I realize this is something I didn't mention. I'm going to up vote because this is on topic and valid, though I'm fairly certain I used the correct credential/URL based on success on 2 out of 3 systems.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here.  I eventually realised that the database went offline before the command was even sent to firebase.  This made sense because there was no error, since it never even sent the request.

Eg. `.set({blah: 123})` does not immediately transmit to the server.  Instead, something is placed on the [node event queue](https://o7planning.org/en/11951/understanding-event-loop-in-nodejs) to execute.  If you let the database go offline too soon, it won't process the queue.

Perhaps (like me) you're calling `admin.database().goOffline();` at the end of the script?  If so, you may just need to defer or delay the offline method until after the transmission.

```
// (TYPESCRIPT)

import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

let app = admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
    databaseURL: "https://blahblah.firebaseio.com/", 
});

admin.database().ref().push({ something: 123 }).then(() => {
    console.log("push complete");

});

// delay before going offline
setTimeout(() => {
    admin.database().goOffline();
    process.abort();
}, 2000);
```