# Firebase-admin fails silently to write to realtime database from nodejs

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, firebase-admin

I’m trying to get setup using [Firebase Admin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data) on my nodejs app running on my Raspberry Pi.

when I call;

`admin.database().ref().child("myPath").push({date: new Date()});`

I’m not receiving any errors but no data is showing up when looking in the Firebase console at my database either.

I also tried chaining on;

`set({date: new Date()});`

and

`push().set({date: new Date()});`

Both also fail to write with no errors.

I've verified that my rtdb url and the project id in the service account file are correct for my database. And I've tried both `require`ing the file as in the docs and passing the credential object directly to;

`admin.credential.cert()`

I only mention that I'm running on Raspberry Pi because the issue I’m seeing sounds very similar to [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41646277/firebase-admin-wont-write-to-database-gives-no-errors) where Firebase Admin won’t write to db. I’m wondering if it’s not coincidental.

Any ideas what I might be missing?

Comment: Did you login with the Firebase CLI first? https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/

Comment: I did not. Didn't see it mentioned in the docs I linked to. Let me give that a try.

Comment: OK, I logged in with Firebase CLI, associated my node project directory with my firebase project, ran `firebase init` and selected the database option. Received a "Firebase initialization complete!" message but still no write to the db using admin.database().ref().child("myPath").push().set({date: new Date()});

Comment: It does show a connection yesterday and today under the usage tab in the project's Firebase console.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what the issue is, but I do find this repo of Firebase example code helpful https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples

Answer (score -1, accepted):

please can you try this code `.....push().set({'date': new Date()});`. Thanks. I am guessing it's takes a String as key and even the `new Date().toStirng()` would be good if i am not wrong.

Thanks,

Comment: Making the property name a string wasn't necessary but calling `.toString()` on the `new Date()` did the trick.

Comment: Thank you Brad, glad it worked for you. Anyways, i only remembered that I need to pass the strings and that's exactly what i suggested. Thanks